# Change color hover menu items (Android)

Tags: android, colors, menu, background, styles

I want to change the background color when you are hover of the menu items using android studio. Help plz. Any example?

I want to change it using the styles pages if is posible.

Thanks you.

Comment: I think you are new to android. You can use "state drawables" to change the background color when focused. You need to define a state drawable and you can use it as a background for any views.

Comment: You are right. I´m going to do that and then I will say you something. Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can try write your own color resourse file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<!--Color for checked state-->
<item android:color="@android:color/white"
      android:state_checked="true"/>

<!--Color for unchecked state-->
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
```

And use this in your menu

```
    app:itemIconTint="@color/your_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/your_colors"
```

Comment: Dont work in menu :S Also, I don´t find the NavigationView. I searched in all the views to try to test it.